# A way to use UML Diagrams between Intellij IDEA Ultimate / CE and other IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, tool-uml

I find IDEA being by far my favourite IDE. 
The only problem i am seeing is that Ultimate editions HAS UML Diagrams, the community edition doesn't have that feature (Code Navigator plugin isn't working on last idea versions as far as i know)
I work a lot with UML in all the processes from engineering to deployment and i can't let other users force switching to Ultimate edition, plus not all using IDEA as their IDE.
I am looking for a third part UML forward and reverse engineering capable that suits my needs of cross-compatibility

Comment: How does using the Ultimate edition on your side force the other team members to use it as well?

Comment: i meant about using UML diagram which are forward and reverse engineering and they're only avaiable  in ultimate version..

Answer (score 1):

You can export class diagrams images coming from your reversed java code and paste it inside your project.

Comment: that's true, do you think it's the most useable way?